# Pass value between void

Tags: android

This is `Service.java`. I want to put `builder` from `onStart` to `onCreate` for make toast.
please help me

```
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    super.onStart(intent, startid);
    Bundle b=intent.getExtras();
    name = b.getStringArray("name");
    builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(String i : name)
    {
         builder.append(i);

     }

}

public void onCreate() {

    Toast.makeText(this, builder, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to use the string value of your [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#toString%28%29) object:

```
public void onCreate() {

    Toast.makeText(this, builder.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Second, but most important is the android activity life cycle:

[image]

`onStart` is called after the `onCreate`, so it is not possible to show datas retrieved in onStart function, inside onCreate. Just put the toast inside the onStart, after creating the stringBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing .toString()

```
Toast.makeText(this, builder.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

A StringBuilder isn't a String itself.

onCreate still can't see the value of builder, since **it's created later**, in onStart().

Comment: builder is working in "void onStart".but in "void onCreate" isn't

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly (you want to use the contents of the `StringBuilder` in `onCreate`):

`onCreate` is before `onStart` in the lifecycle, your builder will be `null` in `onCreate`.

Just show the `Toast` in `onStart` (after building your String) or move all of your code to `onCreate`.

Comment: How can I move to onCreate?

Answer (score 1):

Create builder in onCreate and then make toast and use builder.tostring